# Configure authorized roles dynamically via a config file in MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, configuration, authorization

I current have the following attribute decorating one of the action method.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult DoAdminTask()
{
//Do something

   return View();
}
```

Currently, only users in the Admin role can invoke this method, but this will change. Is there anyway I can store a list of authorised roles in a config file, rather than hard coding it into the source?

EDIT: Roles will change over time, and more than 1 role will need access. 
i.e. Users in either role A **OR** role B can access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No way to do this with the standard authorize attribute, but you could extend the authorize attribute with your own custom authorize attribute and have it use a configuration file to determine the mapping between controller/action and the set of roles.

Comment: Yeah, after more googling, looks like that is the only way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I felt this question deserved an answer with a code sample... Taking @tvanfosson's suggestion of extending the `AuthorizeAttribute` class, here's what I came up with (criticism is more than welcome).

**AuthorizeFromConfiguration.cs**:

```
public class AuthorizeFromConfiguration: AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public new string Roles
    {
        get {
            return base.Roles;
        }
        set {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("authorization.json")
                .Build();
            base.Roles = config[value];
        }
    }
}
```

**authorization.json**:

```
{
    "Parts": {
        "Create": "contoso.com\\MyWebApp_CreateNewPart",
        "Edit": "contoso.com\\MyWebApp_EditPart"
    }
}
```

*Example Usage*:

```
[AuthorizeFromConfiguration(Roles = "Parts:Create")]
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    //...
}
```

Note: In my testing, the web-site had to be restarted before any changes to `authorization.json` file took effect, even when I tried changing the logic so that the JSON file was read on the `get` accessor instead of the `set`.

Answer (score 0):

but you can use something like

```
public static class AppRoles
{
    public const string Users = "UsersRoleName";
    public const string Admin = "AdminRoleName";
}
```

and then Controller can have authorize attribute as

```
[Authorize(Roles = AppRoles.Admin)]
```